# how to change status against id in laravel ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

The issue i am facing is that when i click on active button all the article's active button change to inactive.. i want to change the status of that article id which i set to inactive from active. All articles will remain active or inactive as described status in database.how i can get this?
If i Inactive Article button changes to Inactive of that article which is clicked not all articles and when i refresh page all articles status set to Active but in database their status changed to inactive.

Html:

```
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-article-btn"                                                   
    onclick="deleteArticle({{$article['aID']}})">Active
   </button>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    function deleteArticle(id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '{!! URL('/pay/dash/panel/delete_article') !!}',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'user_id': id},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('Article ID',id);

                if (response == 1) {
                    $('.delete-article-btn').html('Inactive');
                } else {
                    $('.delete-article-btn').html('Active');
                }
            }, error: function (error) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 public function deleteArticles(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->input('user_id');
    $result = 0;

    $checkArticle = Article::where('id', $userId)->where('is_deleted',0)->get();

    if (count($checkArticle)>0) {
        Article::where('id', $userId)->update(['is_deleted' => 1]);
        $result = 1;
    } else {
        Article::where('id', $userId)->update(['is_deleted' => 0]);
        $result = 0;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: try `function deleteArticle(event,id)` and instead of `$('.delete-article-btn').html('Inactive');` try `var target = event.target || event.srcElement;` and `target.innerHTML='inactive'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-article-btn mybtn-{{$article['aID']}}"                                                   
    rel="{{ $article['aID'] }}" rel2="1">Active
   </button>
```

```js
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.delete-article-btn',function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('rel');
         var status = $(this).attr('rel2');
         $.ajax({
            url: '{!! URL('/pay/dash/panel/delete_article') !!}',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'user_id': id,'status':status},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('Article ID',id);

                if (response == 1) {
                    $('.mybtn-'+id).html('Inactive');
                    $('.mybtn-'+id).attr('rel2',0);
                } else {
                    $('.mybtn-'+id).html('Active');
                    $('.mybtn-'+id).attr('rel2',1);
                }
            }, error: function (error) {

            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

```php
public function deleteArticles(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->input('user_id');
    $status = $request->input('status');

    $result = 0;
    if ($status==0) {
        Article::where('id', $userId)->update(['is_deleted' => 1]);
        $result = 1;
    } else {
        Article::where('id', $userId)->update(['is_deleted' => 0]);
        $result = 0;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: same issue all articles chanced to inactive.. and after refresh it shows active where its status changed in database.

Comment: {{$article['aID']}} should bhi unique for every article

Comment: its working but when i refresh page status changed to active not in database.

Comment: yes i tried but its not working even now its not changing status.

Comment: In your article model there should be is_deleted key in fillable array

Comment: so try to print data that you got in controller from ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the the html content of all the buttons with the class ".delete-article-btn"

```
if (response == 1) {
   $('.delete-article-btn').html('Inactive');
} else {
   $('.delete-article-btn').html('Active');
}
```

You have to specify which button you have to update maybe with a data attribute, as you prefer..

```
if (response == 1) {
   $('.delete-article-btn[data-id=X]').html('Inactive');
} else {
   $('.delete-article-btn[data-id=X]').html('Active');
}
```

Also, server side it seems you are targetting ALL articles from an user,
i think you have to get only the Article you want to disable or not.