# Change status with ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel in my project. I have a voucher that maintains a status.
I've used AJAX for changing the status and the AJAX code works successfully.

However the status did not change in my view until after I refresh the page. I'm looking for a way to solve this issue.

```html
<button class="btn btn-link p-0 change" type="submit" data-id="{{ $voucher->id }}">
  @if ($voucher->status == 1)
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on text-success"></i>
  @else
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-off text-muted"></i>
  @endif
</button> 
@if ($voucher->status == 1)
  <span class="badge badge-soft-success">
    enable
  </span> 
@else
  <span class="badge badge-soft-pink">
    disbale
  </span> 
@endif
```

```js
$(".change").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "vouchers/change-status/" + id,
    type: 'put',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      "id": id,
      "_method": 'put',
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log("it Work");
      // $("tr#"+id).remove();
    }
  });

  console.log("It failed");
});
```

Comment: upload the ajax method i will help you...

Comment: I've added but my ajax is ok and it changes status

Comment: dynamically you want change the status right...

Comment: yes that's it exactly the enable and disbale text

Comment: You've not stated exactly how the UI needs to change, but you simply need to execute the logic in the `success` callback to amend the DOM as needed

Comment: Hope this will you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376142/how-to-change-status-against-id-in-laravel-ajax

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I want to change text "enable" and disable dynamicly like the real status that changed

Comment: Blade templates are created on the server, therefore only one of the `@if @else` part will be available to the client. If this is a relatively new project I recommend using a framework like knockout/react/vue/angular as a means to keep a view in sync with an underlying model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

**Blade**

Wrap your code in some holder with class `status-enabled`, when status is `1`. Set special classes for elements which will be visible or not according status.

```html
<div class="holder @if($voucher->status == 1) status-enabled @endif">
    <button class="btn btn-link p-0 change" type="submit" data-id="{{ $voucher->id }}">
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on text-success enabled-visible"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-off text-muted enabled-invisible"></i>
    </button>

    <span class="badge badge-soft-success enabled-visible">
        enable
    </span>

    <span class="badge badge-soft-pink enabled-invisible">
        disbale
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Set rules:

```css
    .holder .enabled-visible {
        display: none;
    }
    .holder .enabled-invisible {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .holder.status-enabled .enabled-visible {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .holder.status-enabled .enabled-invisible {
        display: none;
    }
```

**JS**

Toggle holder class when you have successfuly change status.

```js
$(".change").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "vouchers/change-status/" + id,
        type: 'put',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "_method": 'put',
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        },
        success: function() {
            $(this).closest('.holder').toggleClass('status-enabled');
        }
    });

    console.log("It failed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in your success function:

```
 success: function() {
      console.log("it Work");
      $("i.fa-toggle-on).hide();
      $("i.fa-toggle-off).show();
    }
```

Comment: it change all text I want to change just one row

Answer (score 0):

Html Tag no need of if condition php blade.

```
<button class="btn btn-link p-0 change" type="submit" data-id="{{ $voucher->id }}">
    @if ($voucher->status == 1)
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on text-success"></i>
    @else
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-off text-muted"></i>
    @endif
</button>
<div id="alert-message"></div>  // add this line
@endrole
```

change this code into your code.
script file

```
$(".change").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");

        var success = '<span class="badge badge-soft-success">' +
            'enable' +
            '</span>';

        var failed = '<span class="badge badge-soft-pink">' +
            'disbale' +
            '</span>';
        $.ajax({
            url: "vouchers/change-status/" + id,
            type: 'put',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_method": 'put',
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            },
            success: function() {
                console.log("it Work");
                $('#alert-message').html(success);
                // $("tr#"+id).remove();
            }
        });

        $('#alert-message').html(failed);
    });
```